# Using Notepad ++ I need to remove all text except specific words

Tags: notepad++, find-and-replace

Example: Line 1 is this

```
Adobe Ceiling   EngramEntry_AdobeCeiling_C 106 5 15
```

I want to take out everything except :

```
EngramEntry_AdobeCeiling_C
```

Comment: Unclear. Which words are to be left and on how many lines?

Comment: that is exactly what I want. I need to take out everything before EngramEntry_AdobeCeiling_C and everything after. On each line

Comment: So all the lines are to identically contain only the word `EngramEntry_AdobeCeiling_C`? Why do you need Notepad++ for that?

Comment: There are 500+ lines that have EngramEntry_nameoftheengram_C with a bunch of other stuff before and after that I need to be removed. It's not all the same. Sorry!

Comment: Maybe delimit by space then, you need what comes after the first single or more spaces and before the next single or more spaces after that. I'll leave an actual answer to the Regex or Notepad++ folks! That's an idea though.

Answer (score 2):

Find what: `.+EngramEntry_(.+)_C.+`
Replace with: `EngramEntry_\1_C`

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To be sure to replace **only** lines that contain  `EngramEntry_AdobeCeiling_C` but not `blah_EngramEntry_AdobeCeiling_C_blah`, you have to use [word boundaries](http://www.regular-expressions.info/wordboundaries.html):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^.+?\b(EngramEntry_AdobeCeiling_C)\b.+$`
- Replace with: `$1`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^               # beginning of line
.+?             # 1 or more any character but newline, not greedy
\b              # word boundary, make sure we haven't word character just before
(EngramEntry_AdobeCeiling_C) # group 1, literally
\b              # word boundary, make sure we haven't word character just after
.+              # 1 or more any character but newline
$               # end of line
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1      # content of group 1, i.e. "EngramEntry_AdobeCeiling_C"
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

- Find what: `.+(EngramEntry_AdobeCeiling_C).+`
- Replace with: `\1`
- Search mode: Regular expression

[image: IMG:]